# Using CSS Sprites?

Tags: html, css, sprite

I'm trying to do a navigation bar using css sprites. I have the image but it's just a matter of the code now. At the moment it is:

```
.navi a{
display:block;
float:left;
height:40px;
overflow:hidden;
background-position:left top;
}
navi a:hover img{
margin-top:-40px;
}
```

and the html is:

```
<div class="topbar">
<img alt="title" src="title.png"/><br/>
<div class="navi">
<a href="index.html" class="home"><img src="home_up.png"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

All I have working is the normal image, the height is correct and it crops the rest of the image off, but when I hover it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first style is `.navi a`, but then you are writing: `navi a:hover img`. This means that the second style is applied to every image inside a hovered link which is inside `<navi />` element, and not inside an element which has a classname `navi`.

So instead of:

```
navi a:hover img
```

you should write:

```
.navi a:hover img
```

Comment: haha, i spent so long looking at this. i hate it when it's so simple D:!

Comment: @Jake: I also spent some time before noticing the missing dot. That's why I prefer writing one style per line: it's much easier then to notice the typos like this.